# Mapbox GL JS Convert Screen (X, Y) coordinates to LngLat

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I want to convert a few (X,Y) positions on the mapbox map to their lnglat positions.

I know project() converts from lnglat to X, Y. But, I can't find the reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map.unproject()` exists and does what you need: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#unproject